# How can I get visual studio to deploy my EJS file

Tags: visual-studio, ejs

I deploy my website with visual studio. I'm trying to use [ejs](http://www.embeddedjs.com/).

The website that Visual Studio hosts will not serve my *.ejs templates. The browser gets 404's when looking for my templates.

Can I use EJS with a Visual Studio deployed website?

Answer (score 0):

Change the extensions on your *.ejs templates to *.html. This will get Visual Studio to deploy them so that you can consume them with EJS.